# What does is the "exotic" naming in the version of npm packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

What does it mean the "exotic" naming that appears sometimes in the listing of npm packages on the version, for example in the command `npm outdated` I get:

```
Package       Current       Wanted Latest URL
gulp          4.0.0-alpha.2 exotic exotic github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0
```

thanks

Comment: Going to hazard a guess that the version number `4.0.0-alpha.2` is non-standard due to the alpha suffix; so isn't easily parsed and gets labeled as exotic. If anyone knows why for sure it would be interesting to find out

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think it's labeled as "exotic" because it's installed from a GitHub URL, rather than from the npm registry.  So it's an "exotic" package, meaning foreign or non-native.

My interpretation is that this is a dev-friendly warning that you are doing something "exotic" and that npm/yarn can't detect for you whether this package has become outdated.

I looked in the [`npm/npm`](https://github.com/npm/npm) repo (and some other `npm`-related repos), but I couldn't find the text `exotic`, so it must originate from their (private) registry API? I did find some handling of `exotic` in the [`yarnpkg/yarn`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) repo though, for reference: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/a3ce7c702f644efde783beb8e0b99dc08100f0df/src/package-request.js#L408